# Floating form's input label with UIKit

Tags: css, forms, label, floating, getuikit

Made the following code for the input field and its label:

```
<input id="username" class=uk-input" type="text">
<label for="username">Enter your username</label>
```

Is it possible to make input field's label floating like on the illustration by using just UIKit's techniques?

[image]

I've searched through [UIKit documentation](https://getuikit.com/docs/form) but found nothing related to my question.

If it is impossible with the UIKit then what is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

The UIKit class `uk-form-label` can be used here:

```
<form class="uk-form-stacked">
    <div class="uk-margin">
        <label class="uk-form-label" for="username">Enter your username</label>
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <input class="uk-input" id="username" type="text" placeholder="...">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

More information here: https://getuikit.com/docs/form#layout